# typescript type predicate on array

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am using a function that checks if a variable is an object and not null with:

```
function isRecord(input: any): input is Record<string, any> {
  return input !== null && typeof input === 'object';
}
```

The type predicate ist necessary, so typescript accepts:

```
if (isRecord(x)) {
  console.log(x["att"]);
}
```

I wrote another function that takes an array, but typescript complains with
"Object is possibly 'null'":

```
function areRecords(list: any[]): list is Record<string, any>[] {
  return list.every(element => isRecord(element));
}

if (areRecords(x, y)) {
  console.log(x["att"]);
  console.log(y["att"]);
}
```

The same if I omit "is"

```
function areRecords2(list: any[]): boolean {
  return list.every(element => isRecord(element));
}

if (areRecords2([x, y])) {
  console.log(x["att"]);
  console.log(y["att"]);
}
```

Or if I use rest parameters:

```
function areRecords3(...list: any[]): boolean {
  return list.every(element => isRecord(element));
}

if (areRecords3(x, y)) {
  console.log(x["att"]);
  console.log(y["att"]);
}
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Using the array function, the signature provides that the array is a record holder and not x and y itself.

For example:

```
const list = [x, y];
if (areRecords(list)) {
    // Now typescript knows that list is Record<string, any>[];
    // However, it does not know what x and y is, because
    // the function signature only refers to the array.
}
```

What you can do is:

```
const list = [x, y];
if (areRecords(list)) {
    list.forEach(item => console.log(item["att"]));
}
```

or:

```
const attributes = [x, y].filter(isRecord).map(value => value["att"]);
```